# MYSQL query: get the latest date with grouped by data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table for a chat.

---

### message I senderID I recipentID I date

I want to get a query with the latest messages group by the conversation. (For example if the *'senderID = 1 and the recipentID = 2'* that is the same conversation as *'senderID = 2 and the recipentID = 1'*)

Comment: share sample data and expected output otherwise how we know which column will make group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `in`. MySQL supports tuples with `in`, so here is one method:

```
select c.*
from chats c
where (least(senderID, recipentID), greatest(senderID, recipentID), date) in
       (select least(senderID, recipentID), greatest(senderID, recipentID), max(date)
        from chats c
        group by least(senderID, recipentID), greatest(senderID, recipentID)
       );
```

Comment: Perfect! Works like a charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

- You can identify a specific **conversation** between two people as a [concatenated](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-concat-in-mysql.aspx) string of "[LEAST](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_least.asp) id - [GREATEST](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_greatest.asp) id"
- Use a grouping on the "conversation" to find [Max](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_min_max.asp) date (last message date) for each conversation.
- Use this as a [Derived table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html) resultset, and **Join** to the main table (using `ON` (explicit) and `WHERE` (kind of implicit join))

Try the following query:

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT(LEAST(t1.senderID, t1.recipentID), 
         '-', 
         GREATEST(t1.senderID, t1.recipentID)) AS t1_conversation, 
  t1.*
FROM chat_table AS t1 
JOIN ( 
      SELECT CONCAT(LEAST(t2.senderID, t2.recipentID), '-', 
                    GREATEST(t2.senderID, t2.recipentID)) AS conversation, 
             MAX(t2.date) as last_message_date 
      FROM chat_table AS t2 
      GROUP BY t2.conversation
     ) AS t3 ON t3.max_date = t1.date 
WHERE t1_conversation = t3.conversation
```